# cassandra nodetool status tokens varies

Tags: cassandra

I am using cassandra 1.2.5 and have 4 nodes in a cluster. Initially i have configured num_tokens to 4 in all 4 nodes and later changed to 256. But whenever i run nodetool status it shows tokens only 4. We did nodetool decommission in all 4 nodes and restarted, then it shows tokens 256 for node3 and node4. for node1 and node2 it shows the tokens as 4 only. node1 and node2 are seeds. What should i do to get the tokens as 256?

Because of this the owns for node3 and node4 are 46.9% and  50.7%. and for node1 and node2 it is 1.6 and 0.9%

Comment: Did you clear the whole data and commit log directories after the decommission on all nodes?  num_tokens is only read the first time cassandra starts, so if the old data was present it wouldn't reread it.

Comment: eventhough i deleted the data and commit log directories it is showing 4 only

Comment: sorry, after deleting the data and commit directories i restarted after 5 mins, then it is working fine. Thank you so much.